# Is it safe to schedule NSTimer on Main thread and keep running the timer when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nstimer

I have scheduled and NSTimer on main thread.

```
    func startTimer(){
        MYClass.runUIBlock { () -> Void in
           self.invalidateRecordTimer()
           self.updateTimerForInactiveRecord(self.fiveMinutesInSeconds)
        }
    }

    private func updateTimerForInactiveRecord(timeToRecord:Double){
        recordTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: timeToRecord, target: self, selector:"collectData", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(recordTimer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }
```

The timer keeps on running even if I am in background. Wanted to ask, is it safe to keep the timer ON without invalidating it before the background timer gets over ? Or do I need to check for available background time and invalidate the timer before background timer gets over ?
At present, the timer keeps on running indefinitely in the background.

Answer (score 0):

An NSTimer can run only a max of 10 minutes when in background. Apple has done this purposefully to avoid battery drainage. If you are not supposed to do important activity when in background then as a good citizen it is advised to stop the timer when going in background.

Comment: Even worse, all timers are invalidate when your app goes in the background.